# Implement fold with for-comprehension

Tags: scala

How can a `fold` be implemented as a `for-comprehension` in Scala? I see the only way is to use some recursive call? This is a try that is failing, not sure how to do this? What is the best way to implement `fold` as a `for-comprehension`

```
  val nums = List(1,2,3)                         
  nums.fold(0)(_+_)                              
  def recFold(acc: Int = 0): Int = {
    (for {
        a <- nums
        b = recFold(a + acc)
    } yield b).head
  }                                               
    recFold(0) //Stack overflow
```

Comment: Im not too experienced with scala, but i dont see a base case return from your recursive calls?

Comment: Using `head` is unsafe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `for`, you don't need recursion, but you would need a mutable variable:

```
val nums = List(1,2,3)

def recFold(zero: Int)(op: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = {
  var result: Int = zero
  for { a <- nums } result = op(result, a)
  result
}

recFold(0)(_ + _) // 6
```

Which is pretty similar to how `foldLeft` is actually implemented in `TraversableOnce`:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var result = z
  this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
  result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fold can be implemented both ways right to left or left to right. No need to use `for` plus recursion. Recursion is enough.

```
  def foldRight[A, B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    as match {
      case Nil => z
      case x :: xs => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
    }
  }

  @annotation.tailrec
  def foldLeft[A, B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    as match {
      case Nil => z
      case x :: xs => foldLeft(xs, f(x, z))(f)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was just interested if there where some super smart way to use a for as always seems to be the case in FP...